# Splitting String into Array of Strings Java with || or |

Tags: java

```
 String urls = "http://www.hotmail.com|http://www.google.com.br||http://www.uol.com.br|http://www.ig.com.br||http://www.bol.com.br";
```

How do I remove single and double bars?

I have tried this:

```
String[] resultado =  urls.split("\\|");
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would do some research with regards to the .split() method.

Comment: Remove the bars simple and double and transform into string array

Answer (score 5):

Since your second `|` is optional, use the `?` regex operator.

```
urls.split("\\|\\|?")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String [] array = urls.split("\\|+");
```

Comment: It does not compile and it allows `|||`, `||||` and so on

Comment: It does compile, and IMHO allowing more than one `|` is what the OP wants.

Comment: Why not Daniel? And analysing the context, it's not a problem, because URLs aren't supposed to have pipes.

Comment: @EtienneMiret It was edited, the original code was `urls.split("\|+")`. About more than one: the question says "|| or |".